# The easiet way to put a base64 SVG into HTML DOM by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, base64, decode

Right now, I'm actually using a Base64 SVG as a background-image in CSS. But I like to write the SVG into HTML so that I can easily modify the color of the SVG by CSS...

So here is the question: How can I convert a Base64 SVG into a SVG tag and put into my DOM?

```
var base64SVG = $('#svgHolder').css('background-image');
base64SVG = base64SVG.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '');

// Now I have a Base64 SVG, so what else should I do to be able to put in into the DOM?
```

Actually the content of the `base64SVG` variable is the following:

```
var base64SVG = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3E%3Ccircle r='3' fill='#ccc'/%3E%3C/svg%3E";
```

Comment: Your background image is not Base64 encoded.  I think you mean that it is a Data URI.

Comment: It's an encoded URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this:

```
var svg = decodeURI($('#svgHolder').css('background-image').replace('url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,', '').replace('")', ''));
$('#svgHolder').append(svg); // append the SVG image into the element
$('#svgHolder').css('background-image', 'none'); // And remove the cssbackground-image, as we don't need it anymore
```

It works great! But if anyone knows a better way, I'd be happy to know that :)